# Is it possible to use a notation to denote that $\frac{11\pi}6$ and $-\frac{\pi}6$ have the same location in unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

$\dfrac{11\pi}6$ and $-\dfrac{\pi}6$ have the same location on trigonometry unit circle. My question is how we can denote this property by using mathematical notation between these two fractions? For example $\frac{11\pi}6=-\frac{\pi}6$ is definitely wrong because they have different values. But does $\frac{11\pi}6\equiv-\frac{\pi}6$  makes sense?

Comment: $\frac{11\pi}6\equiv-\frac{\pi}6 \pmod{2\pi}$. See, for instance, ["mod used to describe an angle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793648/409).

Comment: Since, you mentioned unit circle and location, you could prove that they have the same x,y coords on the unit circle by somehow proving that $\cos -\frac{\pi}{6} = \cos \frac{11\pi}{6}$ and $\sin -\frac{\pi}{6} = \sin \frac{11\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your help!

Comment: $$e^{i11\pi/6}=e^{-i\pi/6}$$

Comment: Another word I have seen for angles like this is "coterminal" (i.e. the terminal sides of the angles coincide).